# Can't ping gateway or access outside internet from Ubuntu guest on Windows 10 host

Tags: linux, windows, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Using Virtualbox Version 6.1.16 r140961 (Qt5.6.2) on Windows 10 Home host. When using Bridged Adapter mode on a Ubuntu 20.10 server vm.

I am unable to ping the gateway from the guest. I can ping from the guest to the host and vice versa. However pinging the gateway or the outside internet is not possible. If i switch to NAT i can access the internet. I would like to use the Bridged Adapter mode.

I tried turning off the windows firewall and still no go. When i logged into the router admin panel, i noticed there were no entries in the users list for the guest ip address. I am thinking the Windows Host is somehow configured incorrectly or is preventing access.

Both the guest and the host are on the same subnet, i also tried clearing the arp cache on the windows host as well.

I tried turning off the windows firewall and reinstalling virtual box using administrator rights and only selecting the bridged network adapter to install.

Here are some details from the linux vm when connected with Bridged Mode:
[image]
I can ping the host 192.168.1.47 but not google dns or gateway.

Here are the network settings for the vm:
[image]

Here is when i renew the lease for the ip address from the linux vm:
[image]

What else should i try?

Thanks

Comment: Responding to your second paragraph: Is the Guest wired network adapter set for vanilla DHCP?  It should be.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. @John yeah the guest receives it's ip address automatically. Is that what you mean? Where would i set that?

Comment: DHCP settings on the Guest Network Adapter should let you see outside. That is what I meant.

Comment: Man, you won't believe this. I went to my friends place to try it on his internet connection and router. The problem doesn't occur there, everything works great.

Comment: At this point, try resetting your router to factory specifications and then update the firmware on it.